# Hiding all web page items except for single nested div

Tags: css, html, nested, hide

Suppose my web page has a struture like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="fee">
        <div id="fi">

            <div id="actual_content">

                <p>Content</p>
                <div id="some_important_stuff">Blah</div>
                <p>More content</p>
                <span class="and_another_thing">Meh</span>

                ...
            </div>

            <div id="fo>
                ...
            </div>

            ...
        </div>

        <div id="fum">
            ...
        </div>

        ...
    </div>

    <div id="fazz">
        ...
    </div>

    ...
</body>
```

I want to create a print CSS style that hides everything except for the contents of **actual_content**.

My first attempt was like this:

```
body * {
    display: none; /* Hide everything first */
}

/* Show content div and all of its ancestors */

body > #fee {
    display: block;
}

body > #fee > #fi {
    display: block;
}

body > #fee > #fi > #actual_content {
    display: block;
}

/* Unhide contents of #actual_content */

#actual_content * {
    display: block; /* Not ideal */
}
```

However, since there's no "display: auto" or "display: default", I mess up the styles of **actual_content**'s items when I try to unhide them. I also don't like hard coding the path to **actual_content** since it might change.

Comment: How do you "mess up the styles of actual_content's items when I try to unhide them". Div is by default a block level element and when you set it back to display: block; it should not have any problems. (position: absolute; visibility: hidden; has the same effect as display:none;)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you'd rather not hard code the #actual_content? You could select the first child of the last parent div if the ID is likely to change, for example: div#fi + div would select the first div immediately after #fi.

Comment: @Jawad - I have more than just divs inside the content div.  Objects that display as inlines by default like spans and ems are getting set to display as blocks as well.

Comment: @lowe_22 - When I said hard-coding, I meant the path to **actual_content** (_body > #fee > #fi > #actual_content_). I was hoping that if I removed the **fi** div and put **actual_content** under the **fee** div in the future, the CSS could still handle it.

Comment: How about you do something like this. "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>" - And in the "print.css", you can have - body * {position: absolute; visibility: hidden; } - div#actual_content * {position: static; visibility: visible;}

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use the **[visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)** property. W3Schools **[describes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)** the difference between the display and visibility properties: the visibility property affects the visibility of an element without affecting its structure, i.e. the space it would normally occupy on the page.

Answer (score 4):

on the top level div set `visibility:hidden`, then on the div you want set `visibility:visible`

Comment: just expanding on Ansons answer really

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to go in and target everything that you don't want to show up individually by setting `display:none`. If you can change class names, etc, you should un-nest the `actual_content <div>`, then add classes like `hide_div` to the other `<div>`s so they're easy to turn off.

Answer (score 1):

I know your tags show you want a CSS solution, but the **PrintArea** jQuery plugin is perfect for your needs:

> PrintArea sends a specified dom element to the printer, maintaining
>   the original css styles applied to the element being printed.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/PrintArea